# Let the Cauchy sequences $a_{n}$ and $a'_{n}$ be equivalent. If $b_{n}$ is Cauchy, then prove $a_{n}b_{n}$ is equivalent to $a'_{n}b_{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Suppose the Cauchy sequences $a_{n}$ and $a'_{n}$ are equivalent. If $b_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then prove that $a_{n}b_{n}$ is equivalent to $a'_{n}b_{n}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We have to prove that, for every positive rational $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - a'_{n}b_{n}| \leq\varepsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $n\geq N$. Indeed, let us start by noticing that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - a'_{n}b_{n}| = |b_{n}||a_{n} - a'_{n}| \leq B|a_{n}-a'_{n}|
\end{align*}

This is because $b_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, therefore it is bounded by some positive rational $B > 0$.

Moreover, since $a_{n}$ and $a'_{n}$ are equivalent, for every $\varepsilon/B > 0$, there is a natural number $N \geq 1$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n} - a'_{n}| \leq \varepsilon/B
\end{align*}
whenever $n\geq N$. Thus we conclude that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N\geq 1$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - a'_{n}b_{n}| \leq B|a_{n} - a'_{n}| \leq B\times\frac{\varepsilon}{B} = \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $n\geq N$, and we are done.

Could someone double-check my arguments?

**EDIT**

Two sequences $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are equivalent iff for every positive rational $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N\geq 1$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n} - b_{n}|\leq\varepsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $n\geq N$.

Comment: What does equivalente Cauchy sequences mean? That their difference converges to zero?

Comment: I've edited my question in order to present its definition properly.

Comment: Yeah that looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential part is using the fact $(b_n)$ must be bounded. Yes, your arguments are correct.